# how to build a php memory game without allowing user to cheating

Tags: php, html

this is what i have so far, a table that contains 4 items, you have to match two images with each other. every item has two images front and back just like cards.

```
<table style="padding-left:5px;" width="410" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                <tr> 
                                            <td>
                            <div id="Wrapper">
                                <div class="Card" id="Card1">
                                    <div id="Back1" class="Back">
                                        <img src="/assets/public/images/thumb_60x60_18-Feb-2014/23301.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Back">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Front1" class="Front">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/BlockCover.png" width="90" height="90" alt="Front">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                                                <td>
                            <div id="Wrapper">
                                <div class="Card" id="Card2">
                                    <div id="Back2" class="Back">
                                        <img src="/assets/public/images/thumb_60x60_18-Feb-2014/25662.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Back">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Front2" class="Front">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/BlockCover.png" width="90" height="90" alt="Front">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                                                <td>
                            <div id="Wrapper">
                                <div class="Card" id="Card3">
                                    <div id="Back3" class="Back">
                                        <img src="/assets/public/images/thumb_60x60_18-Feb-2014/22963.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Back">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Front3" class="Front">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/BlockCover.png" width="90" height="90" alt="Front">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                                                <td>
                            <div id="Wrapper">
                                <div class="Card" id="Card4">
                                    <div id="Back4" class="Back">
                                        <img src="/assets/public/images/thumb_60x60_18-Feb-2014/21224.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Back">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Front4" class="Front">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/BlockCover.png" width="90" height="90" alt="Front">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
</table>
```

what i am worried most about is that the user could use the console to **display: none** the div with the **Front** class, which is the cover of the actual image, and then he will immediately know witch match witch. I made sure that no 2 images have the same name

I am  not sure if there is a solution for this but if any of you have an idea please share it with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't give the client any more than the minimum it needs to work.**

In your case, the server should send the client only the covering images. Then, when the client clicks on a block, it should ask the server what's there, and reveal it. From that point on, you can store it in the browser, because it's out of your control: you can't stop the user from just writing down on a piece of paper the block they saw, so there's no point in obscuring it any more - just hide it as you would normally so that the legitimate players can play as normal, and let the cheaters cheat.